# Date Field should populate date everytime, whenever picklist value is changed

Tags: picklist, getpicklistvalues

Whenever a picklist value is changed ( considering I have 3 picklist values in the Picklist field), I want my date field to be updated for today's date. And this update should happen each and every time the picklist value is changed. How can I do this using Workflow rules?

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply with Workflow Rule:

WF Rule Criteria: IsChanged(Picklist_FieldName) && YourDateField != Today()

WF Field Update : Set Today() to the Date Field

Comment: Thanks Naveen, ya issue was solved later , i wasn't abe use IsChanged as i had selected a subsequently meet the criteria condition